# Lucene - How do I query on text and filter numeric range

Tags: java, lucene

Pardon me, but I'm a newbie to Lucene.
I have added documents to my index with multiple fields

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("productName", productName, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new FloatField("price", Float.parseFloat(price), Field.Store.YES));
//+additional fields
```

I would like to search for a product and filter to a price range. Can someone tell me how to apply a filter to these results?

```
String[] queryStrings = {searchTerm}; 
String[] fields = {"itemName"}; //might query multiple fields in future
try {
    Query q = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(luceneVersion, queryStrings, fields, analyzer); // assuming I might want to search additional fields like description in the future
    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory);
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
    TopDocs td = searcher.search(q, to);

    // Not sure how to filter here, I eventually will want to save these results for pagination 

} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FilteringOptions also helps out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you think about adding a [`NumericRangeQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) and combine it with your initial query in a [`BooleanQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html)?
You can combine them using the [`MUST` clause](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanClause.Occur.html#MUST)

Comment: that seems to help me out. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: after some more searching I find that the wiki also helps out. http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/FilteringOptions

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement of combining a search on fields along with a range filter. I ended up with following code

```
Set<String> fieldSet = Sets.newHashSet();
        fieldSet.add(rangeQueryField);

        BooleanQuery fieldsQuery = new BooleanQuery();
        for (String field : fields) {
            fieldSet.add(field);
            WildcardQuery queryPart = new WildcardQuery(new Term(field, queryText));
            fieldsQuery.add(queryPart, Occur.SHOULD);
        }

        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.add(fieldsQuery, Occur.MUST);

        NumericRangeFilter<Long> longNumericRangeFilter = NumericRangeFilter.newLongRange(rangeQueryField, rangeValue, Long.MAX_VALUE, false, false);
        MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(version, fieldSet.toArray(new String[0]), analyzer);
        queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);

        Query q = queryParser.parse(query.toString());
        TopFieldDocs searchResults = searcher.search(q, longNumericRangeFilter, maxResultsToReturn, sort);
```